# Shared textures should be in D3DPOOL_DEFAULT or D3DPOOL_MANAGED?

Tags: c++, directx

I am trying to share a direct3d surface between two processes. They are both using D3D9Ex on Windows 7. The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Sharing_Resources) states:

> To be shared, you need to designate a resource for sharing at the time
>   of creation, and locate the resource in the default pool
>   (D3DPOOL_DEFAULT).

Also:

> To create a shared resource, call any resource creation API (see
>   below) with an uninitialized handle (the pointer itself is not NULL
>   (pSharedHandle != NULL), but the pointer points to a NULL value
>   (*pSharedHandle == NULL)). The API will generate a shared resource and
>   return a valid handle.

So this is my call to CreateTexture to create a shared texture:

```
IDirect3DTexture9* texture;
HANDLE sharedHandle = nullptr;

d3dDevice9Ex->CreateTexture(width, height, 1,
            D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &texture, &sharedHandle);
```

This fails; the output in DgbView.exe is:

```
[8788] Direct3D9: (ERROR) :Failure trying to create a texture
[8788] 
[8788] Direct3D9: (ERROR) :Source of shared texture must be in D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM. CreateTexture fails.
```

I don't get it. It seems like the documentation states the surface must be in D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, but the error message from Direct3D is the surface must be in D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM. Which one is it, or is there anything else wrong with the way I call this method?

Note that when I change the parameter to D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, the error message becomes:

```
[10068] Direct3D9: (ERROR) :Failure trying to create a texture
[10068] 
[10068] Direct3D9: (ERROR) :*pSharedHandle must be a valid pointer to create such D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM texture. CreateTexture fails.
```

Comment: It's a long time since i used d3d9, but im guessing that if you used systemmem, your sharedhandle should point to a valid memory location to store your texture in.

Comment: Possible. I really don't want to use system memory though. I worked around the issue by calling CreateRenderTarget instead, which works for my needs. I still don't understand why the same usage pattern fails for CreateTexture.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but I had the same problem when working with some legacy code.

After stepping into the CreateTexture method disassembly, I found out that there appears to be a bug (or at least undocumented "feature") in the code.

**When using the pSharedHandle to create a shared GPU texture, you must initialize *ppTexture to NULL**

If you don't, the code falls into the path where it tries to use a system bitmap as a texture.

So in the above code, changing

```
IDirect3DTexture9* texture;
```

into

```
IDirect3DTexture9* texture = nullptr;
```

would solve the issue.

Hope this saves anyone the couple of hours I wasted on this.